# Maven Jboss archetypes catalog on eclipse m2e

Tags: maven, jboss, java-ee-6, maven-archetype

Just a simple question since I cannot find the correct url on the Jboss AS 7 started guide. When I'm creating a new project using the maven project wizard... on the archetype selection I cannot find anyone starting with org.jboss.spec.

[image]

I think this is because I need to add something to the maven archetypes catalogs first... but I cannot find the site. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This arche types are available in maven central. `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml`

To add this catalog go to:
Window / Preferences / Maven / Archetype / Add Remote Catalog...

Comment: Hey @Ralph , when I try to add either of these:

    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
    http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

and hit 'Verify', I keep getting 'Remote catalog is empty'. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Vijay Ratnagiri: looks like you missed the `http://` prefix - if you really use `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml` the is should work. I tested it: Found 4321 archetype(s)

Comment: Thanks @Ralph . The http:// was removed by overstock to convert it to a link... I did use http:// and I don't have any proxy setting that are needed... it jsut says the remote catalog is empty. I'm using spring tools suite if that makes any difference.

This is straight forward thing that should work. So, there must be some kind of a network issue or something.

I just downloaded the catalog file and added it as 'Local'. :)